# A kernel function for multi-dimensional dataset

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a kernel function (preferrebly, Gaussian kernel) which takes a multi-dimensional data and outputs a single variable (a number)?

I need such a kernel for this problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16753/which-kernel-function-for-watson-nadaraya-classifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel is not for converting something to number. It is function which convert your data to another space and allow to calculate sclar product in that space. All popular kernel function are used for multi-dimensinal dataset and in combination with SVM regression can be used to predict number or categorical value(SVM classification).
If you interest in converting multidimansinal data to one dimensional space it is useless, because genuine idea of kernel function is to convert to much bigger space to be able to solve problem linearally in that unbelievable complex in number of dimensions space.